# Getting Data from select query for RDLC report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc, ssrs-tablix, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I need to create an RDLC report.
For which I can use only select statements and not any other DB objects as the  database is read only. 
Is there any way in which I can populate the table with data from the query.

Comment: You should be able to perform Select statements from the database if the database is read only. Can you please elaborate on the question?

Comment: @a415 basically I need to create an rdlc report. And for that I need a dataset to feed that as an input to a table. To get that dataset in rdlc I  have to select a table or a view or stored procedure while creating a dataset. I need to bypass that and use an query to get the data.

Comment: @a415 any luck?

Comment: nope nothing...sorry